# Prevent lagging in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

So I am writing a sort of drawing script, and it works fine right now (although the code still needs to be cleaned up and there needs to be more features), but when painting too much, `mousemove` lags incredibly. Here is the main Javascript:

```
   $('#canvas').on('mousedown', function(){
       going = !going;
       $(this).on('mousemove', function(e){
           if(cursor == 'paint' && going == true){
       $('.fall').each(function(){
           if ($(this).css("opacity") == 0){
               $(this).remove();
           };
       });
       var ps = $('#canvas').offset().top;
       var t = (e.pageY - ps - $('.fall').height()).toString() + 'px';
       var l = (e.pageX - $('.fall').width()).toString() + 'px';
       $('.fall').css("margin_left",l);
       $('.fall').css("margin_top",t);
               var doit = '<div class="fall" style="position:absolute;margin-left:' + l + ';margin-top:' + t + ';background-color:'+ color +';box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px ' + color + ';"></div>'
       $('#canvas').prepend(doit); 
           }
           else if(cursor == 'erase'){
           $('.fall').mouseenter(function(){
               $(this).fadeOut('fast',function(){
                   $(this).remove()
               });
           });
       };
   });
```

Essentially, when you click in the section for drawing, if the paint button is clicked, you can draw: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HEnuj/16/).

## My issue:

If you draw too much, especially with starting and stopping, it does not append enough on the `mousemove` do to (I assume) the DOM being overwhelmed.

## Question:

What would be an efficient way to add many many divs to the DOM without creating a lag? Is this possible?

## Note:

this is a personal project and I am not interested in using previously created drawing APIs

Comment: You're adding **another** "mousemove" handler on every "mousedown".  Calling `.on()` does not remove any previous handlers!

Comment: hmmmm I guess that is true! How would I remove the handler?

Comment: There's no need to remove the older handlers; just add that code to the other "mousemove" handler.  Also, the code that updates the "cursor" is extremely expensive. You should try getting the mouse coordinates from the event object instead of interrogating the DOM.

Comment: Also: "mousemove" fires really often. DOM manipulation is extremely expensive.  There's also another "infinite handler" problem with ".fall".

Comment: @Pointy according to chrome inspector heap size is over 10mb after  a few seconds. Do you think mousemove is to blame? if so what can be done?

Comment: @Pointy: there is no other way to "paint" without using the mousemove the way I do (or I can't think of one)...and what problem are you talking about?

Comment: Your code for "erase" is also set up such that the event handler is added over and over again.

Comment: Yes, as I said, the code needs to be greatly cleaned up, and the erase is actually in beta right now anyways

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot you can do to improve performance.

The code below is a heavy refactoring of the code in the question. At first glance it might appear to be less efficient as it has about double the number of lines of the original. However, line count isn't the issue here. Two basic principles apply:

- do as little DOM interaction as possible in the mousemove handler, and as much as possible on mousedown.
- include a "divider circuit" to limit the number of times the mousemove handler is called. This is achieved by detaching the mousemove event handler on every call and reattaching after a short delay, conditional on the mouse still being down.

Also see comments in the code.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    ...
    var $canvas = $("#canvas");
    var data = {
        name: 'fall'//a unique string for namespacing the muousemove event.
    };
    $canvas.on('mousedown', function() {
        going = !going;
        data.$fall = $('.fall');//this collection is created once per mousedown then managed inside mm to avoid unnecessary DOM interaction
        data.mousedown = true;
        data.colorCSS = {
            'background-color': color,
            'box-shadow': '0px 0px 5px ' + color
        };
        data.fallWidth = data.$fall.width();
        data.fallHeight = data.$fall.height();
        attachMouseMoveHandler();
    }).on('mouseup', function() {
        data.mousedown = false;
    }).trigger('mouseup');

    function attachMouseMoveHandler() {
        if(data.mousedown);
            $canvas.on('mousemove.' + data.name, mm);//the event is namespaced so its handler can be removed without affecting other canvas functionality
    }

    //The mousemove handler
    function mm(e) {
        if(going && cursor == 'paint') {
            data.$fall.each(function() {
                data.$fall = data.$fall.not(this);//manage data.$fall rather than re-form at every call of mm()
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.css("opacity") == 0) {
                    $this.remove();
                };
            });
            data.$fall = data.$fall.add($('<div class="fall" />').css(data.colorCSS).prependTo($canvas)).css({
                'margin-left': (e.pageX - data.fallWidth) + 'px',
                'margin-top': (e.pageY - $canvas.offset().top - data.fallHeight) + 'px'
            });
        }
        else if(cursor == 'erase') {
            data.$fall.mouseenter(function() {
                data.$fall = data.$fall.not(this);//manage data.$fall rather than re-form at every call of mm()
                var $this = $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                    $this.remove();
                });
            });
        };
        $canvas.off('mousemove.' + data.name);
        setTimeout(attachMouseMoveHandler, 50);//adjust delay up/down to optimise performance
    }
});
```

*Tested only for syntax*

I had to make a number of assumptions, chiefly concerning what becomes fixed data on mousedown. These assumptions may be incorrect, so you will most probably still have some work to do, but as long as you work inside the overall framework above, there's a good chance that your performance issues will disappear.

Comment: +1, great explanation and code seems very very promising, but when I tried to implement it into my jsfiddle, it broke the fiddle...maybe I am placing it wrong?

Comment: I just made a minor but potentially significant mod to the code in the answer. `data.$fall.add` now reads `data.$fall = data.$fall.add(...`. If this doesn't fix the fiddle then I would need to see it to make a judgment as to what's wrong.

Comment: I linked the jsfiddle showing everything in the question...here is a jsfiddle using your code that works: http://jsfiddle.net/xyuBJ/1/ ... when you compare them, yours lags less, but is much worse at drawing unless you remove the delay...but then that adds lag...is this even possible?

Comment: Sorry I didn't even notice the fiddle link. Agreed performance is poor. I guess there must be specialized HTML5/canvas techniques for optimising an application like this - stuff I'm not aware of. Can only suggest you do some research and maybe find some working examples of similar apps - see if they work any better - if so then you know what to aim for.